# How do I solve this inequality $126-21x < 112-16x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do I solve this inequality $126-21x < 112-16x$?
If there were this sign $=$ , I would be able to solve it easily. But I am not able to do it because there is $<$. How can I find the value of $x$? Please help.

Comment: Bring the $21x$ to the RHS, the $112$ to the LHS, divide. As a caution (not a problem here), always watch dividing/multiplying by a negative when solving these as it swaps the inequality direction. Now, resolve it by bringing the $16x$ to the LHS.

Comment: Operations on inequalities work similar to the operations on equalities. You only need to be careful, when multiplying or deviding by something negative. Then the inequality sign must be switched. 
For example:
$3>1$ but $-3<-1$ (here I multiplied by $-1$).

Comment: You have correctly realized that this *thing* has $<$ instead of $=$. Hence this *thing* is called an inequation instead of an equation. Just for terminology sake.

Comment: What properties about inequality do you know?

Comment: Re: answerers: How many ways to say $x \gt \frac {14}{5}$.  This is not the kind of question that warrants five answers saying pretty much the same thing, and I see many of you, due to your invested interested of gaining rep, upvoted the question.

Comment: In general, it is advised to [provide some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for the question. If you do not have other idea how to add context, showing your own work or what you know what be probably enough. Since you wrote you can solve $$126-21x = 112-16x$, I suppose adding the solution of this equation would not be too much work for you. And I guess you would not get that many downvotes and close votes, if you had done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an **inequality**. Instead of just solving it for one value of $x$ (like what you would do if you had an "$=$" sign, we solve for any value of $x$ that makes the statement given true.). We can solve this **almost** like an equation. There are only a couple caveats: 
$$
126-21x < 112-16x\iff 126<112-16x+21x\iff 126-112<5x\\
\iff 14<5x\iff \frac{14}{5}< x
$$
So, we now know that **any** value of $x$ greater than $\frac{14}{5}$ will make the inequality true.

For example, $x=6$, we have $126-21\cdot 6=126-126=0$ for the left hand side and $112-16\cdot 6=112-96=16$ for the right hand side which is indeed greater than the left hand side. You could also check this for $x=5,7, 5.5, 5.1, 100, etc.$.

The caveat that I mentioned above is if we have something like $$-5x<10$$
Then, when we divide by a negative number, we have to "flip" the inequality sign like so: $$-5x<10\iff x> -2$$
You should think about why this is and it may help to have a number line nearby if you're not too familiar with this. Also, this is true for multiplication by negative numbers (multiplication and division are practically the same thing).

Comment: If you use left-to-right implications, you show only that *if* there is a solution $x$, then $x>\frac{14}{5}$. To show that *every* $x$ with $x>\frac{14}{5}$ is a solution, you need the right-to-left implications (of course, these hold as well in this case).

Comment: @Uwe Feel free to edit it. I didn't mean the implications as strictly "if"'s, but just as "here is the next step". Of course, technically, you're correct Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This equation can be solved for $x$ using rules you already learnt for elementary algebra.

We have: $126-21x<112-16x\Leftrightarrow 126<112+5x$

$\hspace{61 mm}\Leftrightarrow 14<5x$

$\hspace{61 mm}\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{14}{5}<x$

It's conventional to express equations with the variable on the left-hand side.

We just flip the direction of the inequality:

$\hspace{61 mm}\Leftrightarrow x>\dfrac{14}{5}$

Therefore, the solution to the equation is $x>\dfrac{14}{5}$.

Comment: You should use equivalence arrows, not just implication arrows.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle these inequalities pretty much like equalities, except that when you multiply or divide both sides by a negative number, the direction of the operator flips, e.g. from $<$ to $>$.
\begin{align}
126 - 21 x &< 112 - 16 x \iff \\
126 &< 112 - 16 x + 21 x = 112 + 5 x \iff \\
126 - 112 = 14 &< 5 x \iff \\
14/5 &< x
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$126-21x\lt 112-16x$

$\implies 14\lt 5x$

$\implies x\gt \frac{14}{5}$

so all values grater than $\frac{14}{5}$ are the solutions of given inequality

Comment: That's the third answer within 25 minutes that gets the implication arrows wrong (see @anonymaker000010001 and @TazwarSikder).

Answer (score 1):

You could treat it as an **equation** and solve it for $x$. Afterwards try something *smaller* or something *bigger* than your solution (best try would be $0$).
The solution of the inequality then are all numbers smaller or bigger than $x$ according to which gave you a true result for your **original inequality**.

e.g. $52 - 3x < 10 +4x$.

Treat it as an equation: $52-3x=10+4x$ and get $x=6$. Try something smaller $x=0$:
$$52-3\cdot 0 = 52 < 10 = 10 + 4 \cdot0$$ is **not true**, so the solution to the problem $52 - 3x < 10 +4x$ are *all numbers greater* *than* $6$.